# Where to find logs for databricks workspace?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I created a databricks component with an vnet based on this [template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-databricks-all-in-one-template-for-vnet-injection/) and [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html). The problem is that we receive an error when trying to launch a workspace.

> "We've encountered an error creating your workspace. Please wait a few minutes and try again."

[image]

In the documentation, there is a similar error in [troubleshooting section](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html#troubleshooting) but it's not the same.

The problem could be a network problem as the documentation suggests, but the ARM has been probed in other azure environments and it works properly.

The problem is creating a workspace but we don't know why.

Does anyone know where to find any kind of logs about workspace creation or know anything about this error message?

Thanks.

Comment: Would the activity log in the Azure Databricks resource in the Azure Portal show anything that could be helpful?

Comment: nothing about errors, only informational. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that your workspace failed to be provisioned. We had this when a Policy on our subscription blocked the resource from being created. The policy was to ensure that Tags were set. Check to see if you have any Policies enabled.

Any logs you can see will be in the resource group under the deployments blade. But it probably won't show anything useful. You should raise a support ticket if you cannot track the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the templates deployment for the resource group and managed resource group mark everything as Succeeded.  All policies checked and they have no effect. May be is a permissions problem or networking. First step talking with subscription owner in order to execute with elevated permissions, second call Microsoft, if step 1 does not work. +1

Comment: Finally the problem was a naming policy that was affecting to other component that is created with databricks, a network intent policy that can not be created properly. I mark this awswer as corect.